# Tradução de "unaccept"

Tags: debate, bug, status-pronto, localização

Percebi que quando uma resposta é desmarcada como aceita, aparece "não aceitar" no histórico de reputação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meio estranho isso, não acham? Porque a ação foi de "desaceitar", e não de "não aceitar". Eu ia dizer que "desaceitar" é uma palavra que não existe, mas segundo o [VOLP](http://www.academia.org.br/abl/cgi/cgilua.exe/sys/start.htm?sid=23) ela existe sim! Então sugiro que troquemos "não aceitar" por <strike>"desaceitar"</strike> "desaceitação". Se prefere outra coisa, dê sua sugestão como resposta aí embaixo (lembrando que o texto deve ser o mais curto possível).

Comment: Não entendi porque no infinitivo. Pra mim o certo seria **"desaceito"**.

Comment: É mesmo, o infinitivo é estranho. Mas "desaceito" também é :)

Comment: Quando li "não aceitar" na imagem, primeiro pensei que aquilo é um link, uma ação. Só depois percebi que era uma informação de algo que já aconteceu. Por isso "desaceito" descreve melhor, IMHO.

Comment: É, infinitivo não serve mesmo. Antes estava tudo no infinitivo, "votar a favor", "votar contra" etc., mas o Gabe corrigiu. Esse aí deve ter sobrado, com o duplo erro.

Comment: Andrey, mudei minha sugestão para "desaceitação". Por que você não posta a sua como resposta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Procurei no Google o significado de "desaceito" e encontrei:

> adj (des+aceito) 1 Que não foi aceito. 2 Recusado. 3 Mal-apreciado.
>
> <sub>http://www.dicio.com.br/desaceito/</sub>

Assim, pensando melhor, acho que "desaceito" não seria a palavra correta neste caso. Pois aqui temos algo que tinha sido aceito, mas isso foi desfeito.

Procurei por "desaceitado" e não encontrei nada. Acho que esta palavra não existe.

---

## Minha sugestão

Sugiro algo como "**aceitação retirada**" ou "**aceitação desfeita**."

Comment: "que não foi aceite" aqui em PT usa se assim, não sei qual das duas está certa ou se estão as duas formas.

Comment: https://priberam.pt/dlpo/desaceitado

Comment: gostei de "desfeita aceitação", mas prefiro "**aceitação desfeita**"

Comment: @Jorge Tem razão. Corrigido.

Comment: O Gabe mudou para "aceitação desfeita".

Answer (score 2):

"Desaceito" não me soa nada bem. Prefiro "**desaceitada**", mas também concordo com "desaceitação".

Além disso fica melhor "A sua resposta foi desaceitada" do que "A sua resposta foi desaceito". Eu não tenho a certeza absoluta mas acho que neste caso é errado dizer "desaceito".

Obs: Eu tento sempre conjugar as palavras que aparecem por aqui, com a frase que elas querem dizer, como fiz aqui em cima

PS: O meu dicionário do Firefox diz que todas as opções dentro de aspas estão incorretas ;)

Comment: Também prefiro "desaceita".

Answer (score 0):

`recusada` não seria melhor?

Que conforme informou o @Andrey elas tem o mesmo significado?

Comment: Acho forte demais. Você marcou uma resposta como aceita, depois achou melhor escolher outra. Não significa que a primeira foi "recusada".